# Sync only good face pictures with iOS devices

Tags: itunes, sync, photos, ios

I have a lot of pictures in Aperture. A lot of them are not very good and just in the library for backup reasons / whatever.

When I sync my iOS devices with iTunes, I have the option to either sync ALL pictures (also the pictures I don't want) or some selected pictures only.

I can have a smart album that allows me to sync all good pictures, but this won't keep the album structure they are in. But this is fine.

One thing that really annoys me is: If I want to sync faces, it adds all the images I don't care about. So instead of 100 pictures of a person, it wants to sync 400.

Is there any smart way to tell iTunes, that it should not add more photos when syncing the face meta data, but just sync the meta data for the existing photos that get synced anyways?

Answer (score 0):

I just saw, that it now does this automatically. When one of the synced images contains faces, they get added to the library on your iDevice.